# jQuery hide element when printing not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this script to print a specific element

```
$(".bottom-meta a").click(function () {
    var contents = $(this).closest('.special-offer-item').html();
    var frame1 = $('<iframe />');
    frame1[0].name = "frame1";
    frame1.css({ "position": "absolute", "top": "-1000000px" });
    $("body").append(frame1);
    var frameDoc = frame1[0].contentWindow ? frame1[0].contentWindow : frame1[0].contentDocument.document ? frame1[0].contentDocument.document : frame1[0].contentDocument;
    frameDoc.document.open();
    frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>Special Offers</title>');
    frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
    //Append the external CSS file.
    frameDoc.document.write('<link href="https://www.website.com/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
    //Append the DIV contents.
    frameDoc.document.write('<h2 style="margin-top: 120px;">Specials</span></h2>');
    frameDoc.document.write(contents);
    frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
    frameDoc.document.close();
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.frames["frame1"].focus();
        window.frames["frame1"].print();
        frame1.remove();
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

However, I can't hide elements that I want to hide.

```
@media print {
  .no-print {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

<div class="bottom-meta">
    <p>EXP 11-26-2020</p>
    <a href="#" class="no-print"> Print Coupon</a>
</div>
```

in style.css, as a separate stylesheet and inline in the script but that element keeps printing.

Comment: When you inspect the `Print Coupon` link, are there any other css rules that have a higher specificity?

Comment: No, I added !important but forgot to include it above.

Comment: Since you're using JavaScript to print why not use JS to also hide the element?

Comment: Actually, I put the .no-print style in the wrong stylesheet. Once I put it in the stylesheet called in the code, it worked. My bad!

Comment: You can simply move the not-wanted-print content outside of `.special-offer-item`...